# Using R to merge two datasets

Tags: r

I'm a newby to R and I can't seem to figure out how to merge two datasets. The examples that I've found in manuals use the merge function to merge data with a unique identifier but that's not what I want. I simply want to add additional rows of data from my dataset #2 into dataset #1.

Comment: Part of why you may be having a hard time finding the answer to your question is because adding rows to an existing set is sometimes called "appending" data, rather than merging it (which is associated with a join).

Comment: if you have two dataframes with unequal columns then you may want to look at rbind.fill in `plyr` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the two data sets have the same variables, you can use rbind to merge two data sets

```
    total <- rbind(data frameA, data frameB)
```

If the number of variables are different - you can create additional variables in the data frame that has lesser number of variables, set them to NA and then merge